# I'm unable to access my factory data in my angular controller, but it works in the view

Tags: angularjs, factory

I'm having an odd problem where I can't actually access the data from my factory in the controller, but it works fine in the view using ng-repeat.

Factory:

```
function Lists($resource){
    console.log("Lists factory envoked")
    var Lists = $resource("/expenses", {}, {
      update: {method: "PUT"}
    })
    Lists.all = Lists.query();
    return Lists
  };
```

Controller:

```
function listController(Lists){
  var vm = this
  vm.lists = Lists.all
};
```

Router Function:

```
    .state("list", {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "/assets/html/list.html",
  controller: "listController",
  controllerAs: "listsVM"
})
```

More code:

```
.factory("Lists", [
    "$resource",
    Lists
])
.controller("listController", [
   "Lists",
   "$scope",
   listController
])
```

The ng-repeat `data-ng-repeat="list in listsVM.lists"` works fine and is displaying my data correctly.  However, when I try to access vm.lists in the controller, I can't get to my data.  When I console.log vm.lists.length I get undefined.  Here is a screen shot of when I do console.log(vm.lists):[console.log(vm.lists)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvvtX.png)

How do I access this data in the controller?

Comment: `vm.lists` is undefined when you are trying to `console.log` because the request has not completed yet. On the other hand ng-repeat will work just fine because when the the lists variable gets data the result will be displayed in the view

Comment: I needed to grab the factory results with a .then()